# Enum in Annotations

Tags: java, static, enums, annotations

I have an annotation I can't change which expects two `String` arguments.

I'd like to use it like this:

```
@RequestMapping( MyUrls.FOO.a, MyUrls.FOO.b )
```

This is how I imagined implementing it

```
public enum MyUrls {
    FOO("a", "b"), 
    BAR("c", "d");

    public String a, b;
    MyUrls(String a, String b) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }
}
```

This doesn't work since `a` or `b` can't be statically resolved.

**What alternatives** do I have which are *nicer* than:

```
class MyUrls {
    public static String FOO_A = "";
    public static String FOO_B = "";
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a static inner class to group your strings.

```
class MyUrls {
    public static final class Foo{
       public static final String A = "";
       public static final String B = "";
       // ...
    }
}
//works as
MyUrls.Foo.A
```

Answer (score 3):

Although your question does not look like a question but as a declaration, I agree with you. 
You cannot use enum members when you are defining annotations. Only "real" constants, i.e. static final fields and constant expressions are applicable. So, there is no good alternative right now.